# question on Proj

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If $X$ is a projective variety with homogeneous coordinate ring $S(X)$, is it true that $$\text{Proj}(S(X)) \cong X$$

I think I'm missing some key point in the understanding here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly correct, except that $X$ only has a homogeneous coordinate ring after you fix an embedding $X\subseteq\Bbb P^n$. For different embeddings, the homogeneous coordinate rings can be nonisomorphic. One common example for this is the Veronese embedding: Take a degree $d$ hypersurface $X\subseteq\Bbb P^n$. Its image under the $d$-th Veronese $\nu_d:\Bbb P^n\to \Bbb P^m$ is a hyperplane.